# Find Cell Range Based on Two Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I've put together some VBA to find the last row with a certain criterion that matches the current value in my loop, then take action. This VBA code works, until I realized that the worksheet can contain the matching value multiple times but with different dates in another column. So I'm now trying to add a second search criterion to my VBA.

Here is the snippet of VBA as of now.

```
   For Each t In trans.Cells
            On Error GoTo NxtT2
                If t.Value = Empty Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                    ty = t.Offset(0, -3).Value
                    tx = t.Offset(0, -6).Value
                    Set searchTerm = .Range("E:E")
                    Set where = searchTerm.Find(what:=ty, after:=searchTerm(1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
                        If t.Offset(0, -3).Value = where.Value And IsError(where.Offset(0, 3).Value) Then
                            t.Value = "#N/A"
                        End If
                End If

NxtT:
    On Error GoTo 0
    If t.Offset(1, -3).Value = "" Then Exit For
    Next t

NxtT2:
    Resume NxtT
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is make the line `Set where = searchTerm.Find(what:=ty, after:=searchTerm(1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)` to also include the `tx`value along with the `ty` that is already in there.

Something like this, if possible?

```
Set where = searchTerm.Find(what:=ty & tx, after:=searchTerm(1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
```

But I know that is not the correct syntax for it.

Any advice on how to approach this in the simplest way?

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to find the first term and then check if the other cell matches and if not continue the Find.

Comment: If there is a set layout maybe you could try autofiltering?

Comment: Hmmm... `Else: End If`. Did he forget to put code in there? So hard to tell... _Please_ get rid of useless `Else` clauses. They're not necessary and only lead to confusion! Get rid of the `GoTo NxtT`, as well, after processing the `If t.Value...`, the `NxtT:` line is the next thing processed anyway. You can ditch the `NxtT2:` label and just `On Error Goto NxtT`, since that's effectively what your code does anyway. `Then GoTo Finish` should just be `Exit For`, which (once you ditch `NxtT2:`) will drop to where your `Finish:` label is anyway...

Comment: Sorry... Code Review, not really addressing the issue at hand, but that just screamed at me.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for the advice, I cleaned up some of the code as you recommended. However, the labels I had were to clear the error. I will regularly come across a value error in the data, and removing the Resume Next label causes the code to error since it didn't properly leave the first error.

Comment: Glad you took that constructively! Not sure I completely follow you, maybe you should post the updated code - the only line that's covered by `On Error GoTo NxtT2` is the line immediately following. If that errors, you'll end up at `NxtT:`, but take 2 jumps to get there (via `NxtT2:`) instead of just one...

Comment: @FreeMan I updated the code. The issue with it now, as currently showing above, is that when the loop comes across a second error, it is not truly exited or resumed from the first error. So the "Run-Time error 13: Type mismatch" occurs. I guess what is missing now is a proper way to fully exit the error handler each time.

Comment: Based on the _current_ version of the code, when the `For Each t...` loop completes, the next line it will execute is `Resume NxtT`. I'm not sure what VBA will do when it hits `Resume` when it's not in "error handling mode" but if it doesn't error there, it most certainly will when it gets to `Next t` with a "Next without For" RTE.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the original question, but to the issue I created with my off-the-cuff code review.

Your error handling never properly wrapped up. The code still thought it was in the error handler because you "exited" the error handler with the `Next`, which you really can't do - you need to leave this "instance" of error handling with a `Resume`.

Give this a shot instead for the cleaned up error handling.

*NOTE: I declared variables because I've got `Option Explicit` set, which you also should also have. I've made the brash assumption that you've got your variables declared outside the code you shared. Use the variables as you've declared them, not as my quickie patched `Variant` declarations.*

```
Sub foo()
  Dim t As Variant
  Dim ty As Variant
  Dim tx As Variant
  For Each t In Cells
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If t.Value = Empty Then
      On Error GoTo 0
      ty = t.Offset(0, -3).Value
      tx = t.Offset(0, -6).Value
      Dim searchterm As Range
      Set searchterm = .Range("E:E")
      Dim where As Range
      Set where = searchterm.Find(what:=ty, after:=searchterm(1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
      If t.Offset(0, -3).Value = where.Value And IsError(where.Offset(0, 3).Value) Then
        t.Value = "#N/A"
      End If
    End If

Continue:
  Next 

CleanExit:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    If t.Offset(1, -3).Value = "" Then
      Resume CleanExit
    Else
      Resume Continue
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't this also be achieved with even fewer labels and IF statements by handling as I have just now edited my above code to show?
EDIT: Also, you are correct, I have by variables declared and Option Explicit set, I just didn't bother posted that part :)